# How to dynamically execute one of the query in a Union?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I want to execute one of the two queries here based on a parameter.
The parameter could be a Yes/No Flag. Based on 'Yes' value, first query should get executed, and so as the second based on 'No'.

```
SELECT per.PERSONAL_NUM as EMP_NUM,per.FIRST_NAME||' '||MIDDLE_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME AS NAME,per.EMPLOYEE_TYPE
  FROM PER_EMPLOYEE_MST per
  WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE (:pname)||'%'

  UNION ALL 

  SELECT dep.DEPUT_PERS_NUM as EMP_NUM,dep.FIRST_NAME||' '||MIDDLE_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME AS NAME,dep.EMPLOYEE_TYPE
  FROM PER_DEPUTATION_MST dep
  WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE (:pname)||'%'

  ORDER BY NAME
```

Comment: @Martin Smith  , you should guess

Comment: @RoyiNamir - My guess is Oracle. Do I win something?

Comment: which SQL? MySQL, MSSQL...? try working with `IF` statement

Comment: @Martin Smith , you got yourself microsoft works 1998 CD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make checking the flag part of the `WHERE` clause of each part, so they will return no rows if they aren't appropriate:

```
SELECT per.PERSONAL_NUM as EMP_NUM,per.FIRST_NAME||' '||MIDDLE_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME AS NAME,per.EMPLOYEE_TYPE FROM PER_EMPLOYEE_MST per WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE (:pname)||'%' AND :flag = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT dep.DEPUT_PERS_NUM as EMP_NUM,dep.FIRST_NAME||' '||MIDDLE_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME AS NAME,dep.EMPLOYEE_TYPE FROM PER_DEPUTATION_MST dep WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE (:pname)||'%' AND :flag = 0

ORDER BY NAME
```

Comment: I agree that this directly answers the question asked, but is it really advisable to do this as a UNION rather than have it in an IF block?

Comment: It *should* be more or less equivalent in performance (it shouldn't be hard for the analyser to realise it doesn't have to examine any actual rows), and it can be the way to go in some cases - in particular the above is more easily used as part of a larger query than something using IF.